# STR_TO_DATE returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert a string to date with a format of yyyy/mm to yyyy

```
STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(time,1,4), '%Y')
```

This returns null for every value as well as when I try to convert without getting rid of the mm:

```
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(time,'/',''), '%Y%m')
```

This method has worked for me before, I'm at a loss for what I'm missing.
Thanks in advance!

Edit for clarification:
Eventually I am going to insert the year into a column with data type year, so I need to convert a varchar to a date type so I can extract the year in order to insert the data into a new table

I am in the process of making sure it will work before populating the new column with a command like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (year)    
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(time,1,4), '%Y')    
FROM `origtable`
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to convert a string to date with a format of yyyy/mm to yyyy

Just use `left()`:

```
select left(time, 4) as yyyy
```

There is no need to convert to a date or datetime.  You want a simple string operation.

EDIT:

`year` is a really weird type.  I would just use an integer.  But if you are using it, you can insert a full date into the field:

```
select date(concat(time, '/01'))
```

The resulting date can be inserting to a `year` column.

Comment: Eventually I am going to insert the year into a column with data type year, so I need to convert a varchar to a date type so I can extract the year in order to insert the data into a new table

Comment: the current data type of time is varchar